# CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice contains unexpected matrix values, but why?

Tags: wpf, dpi

I'm currently using PixelLab's BOT (Bag o' Tricks) for its `ReorderListBox` control, but I've noticed some major slowdowns on the mousedown of a list item.

I've tracked it down to the way the control creates its `DragPreviewAdorner`, specifically the `GetCurrentDPI` method, which is implemented simply as:

```
Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(visual)
                               .CompositionTarget
                                 .TransformToDevice;
x = 96 / m.M11;
y = 96 / m.M22;
```

Thing is, for my list items, `M11` and `M22` are coming back as *tiny* numbers, thereby giving very large DPI (x = 100000, and y = 5500). Consequently, the calling code ends up creating an enormous in-memory bitmap, which in turn causes a delay when garbage collected.

My question is: what might be causing these seemingly erroneous values in the transform? Everything looks fine on-screen. :-/

Thanks.

Comment: Starting to think the debugger must've been lying to me about variables' values, as I can't repeat these numbers now. However, the call to the `RenderTargetBitmap` ctor is still taking ages, despite the bitmap being a perfectly reasonable size (approx 1000 x 60). Seems like it's triggering garbage collection regardless.